# Knowing if a specific column exists or not

Tags: mysql, sql, web-applications, sql-injection

**Hi,** when entering the following url (for learning purpose only) I can see an image with id=1.

So I tried this to find the names of some tables inside the database, and it worked. This can detect if a table starting with 'albu' exists or not:

> http://35.227.24.107:5001/d0510b3060/fetch?id=1 AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'albu%')>0; --

But how could I know if a specific column that its name starts with `'albu'` exists or not? I already tried this, but it didn't work:

> http://35.227.24.107:5001/d0510b3060/fetch?id=1 AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'albums' AND column_name LIKE 'albu%')>0; --

**Please Note: for my question, I know both the name of the db and the table.**

Comment: *But didn't work* meaning?

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES contains information on tables, but not on columns. That will be in the COLUMNS view...

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Shadow, you are looking for [MySQL `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html) :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'albums' AND column_name LIKE 'albu%'
```

NB : you might also want to filter on the `TABLE_SCHEMA`. It takes the schema *and* the table name to uniquely identify a table in the database.